# Apply a function based on rows position in a subset

Tags: r

I'm trying to compute an Index, but i'm stuck with a step of the formula implying dates.

Here is a part of my input:

```
YEAR     RN       DATE                      NOM                                        SITE LONG     SP                                SUMNB     NB100
2010 RNN157 2010-04-22 COMBE LAVAUX-JEAN ROLAND   RNN157-Combe Lavaux 01 Sentier des crêtes    111 Anthocharis cardamines (Linnaeus, 1758)     1 0.9009009
2010 RNN157 2010-04-26 COMBE LAVAUX-JEAN ROLAND   RNN157-Combe Lavaux 01 Sentier des crêtes    111 Anthocharis cardamines (Linnaeus, 1758)     1 0.9009009
2010 RNN157 2010-03-22 COMBE LAVAUX-JEAN ROLAND   RNN157-Combe Lavaux 01 Sentier des crêtes    111 Anthocharis cardamines (Linnaeus, 1758)     0 0.0000000
2010 RNN157 2010-09-29 COMBE LAVAUX-JEAN ROLAND   RNN157-Combe Lavaux 01 Sentier des crêtes    111 Anthocharis cardamines (Linnaeus, 1758)     0 0.0000000
2010 RNN157 2010-05-18 COMBE LAVAUX-JEAN ROLAND   RNN157-Combe Lavaux 06 Friches parc de nuit    111 Anthocharis cardamines (Linnaeus, 1758)     1 0.9009009
2010 RNN157 2010-04-15 COMBE LAVAUX-JEAN ROLAND   RNN157-Combe Lavaux 06 Friches parc de nuit    111 Anthocharis cardamines (Linnaeus, 1758)     0 0.0000000
2010 RNN157 2010-09-29 COMBE LAVAUX-JEAN ROLAND   RNN157-Combe Lavaux 06 Friches parc de nuit    111 Anthocharis cardamines (Linnaeus, 1758)     0 0.0000000
```

For each row within each YEAR/SITE/SP subset, I need to compute the time difference in days between the date of a row, and the date of the previous row ((Row x) - (row x-1)). Then the result will be stored in a new column.

I have found some functions on SO allowing to calculate things with row position, but since i'm using dates,and for obscure reasons, it returns me dates like 1970.

```
>DF[, DIFF := DATE - c(NA, DATE[seq_len(.N-1)])][]
 SP                                     SUMNB NB100       DIFF
Anthocharis cardamines (Linnaeus, 1758)     1 0.9009009       <NA>
Anthocharis cardamines (Linnaeus, 1758)     1 0.9009009 1970-01-05
Anthocharis cardamines (Linnaeus, 1758)     0 0.0000000 1969-11-27
Anthocharis cardamines (Linnaeus, 1758)     0 0.0000000 1970-07-11
Anthocharis cardamines (Linnaeus, 1758)     1 0.9009009 1969-08-20
Anthocharis cardamines (Linnaeus, 1758)     0 0.0000000 1969-11-29
Anthocharis cardamines (Linnaeus, 1758)     0 0.0000000 1970-06-17
```

I didn't yet reach the point where i'm adding this formula in a tapply function in order to apply this to the subsets.

Since I failed in mixing this with difftime(), do you have some ideas about how i can get the difference in days?

Comment: how about as.numeric(DIFF)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`?Dates`says:

> Dates are represented as the number of days since 1970-01-01, with
>   negative values for earlier dates.

So the values in `DIFF` are date differences in days, which are then converted to date objects.

What's wrong with `diff()`?

```
# example data
set.seed(1)
dates <- seq(as.Date("2012-01-01"), as.Date("2013-12-31"), by="day")
dates <- dates[sort(sample(1:length(dates), size=length(dates)*.50))]
DF <- data.frame(DATES=dates)

# date diffs
DF <- transform(DF, DIFF = c(NA, diff(DATES)))
#        DATES DIFF
# 1 2012-01-09   NA
# 2 2012-01-10    1
# 3 2012-01-13    3
# 4 2012-01-16    3
# 5 2012-01-22    6
# 6 2012-01-24    2
```

Comment: Oh, i should have known that! Thanks!